# Extending visa in a different European country

Tags: visas, schengen, germany, spain

Currently I'm studying in the Czech Republic with the Erasmus program. Therefore I have the long stay student visa which will end at the beginning of July. However I want to stay in Europe during the summer. Perhaps for internship or for a language school. However I don't know if I can extend my visa as a Spain visa or Germany visa.

I know that I can extend my visa in the Czech Republic but they also require a legitimate reason for the stay, which I won't have, since I want to stay in a different country. I've tried to reach the consulates in the Czech Republic but they give information either in Czech or Spanish.

I'd be so grateful if someone with a similar experience can guide me!

Answer (score 3):

You can't *extend* one country's type D visa in another country.

However, there's nothing that says that Spain or Germany cannot issue a *separate* visa that commences right when your type D expires. You just have to convince them to do so, same as if  you *didn't* have the type D visa.

That may be easier said than done, though. Spain and Germany are not supposed to issue *short-stay* Schengen visas unless you apply from your country of *permanent* residence, which is not Czechia. They can dispense from that in special circumstances, but whether you can convince them that your circumstances are sufficiently special is anyone's guess.

Member states follow their own rules for issuing their own type D visas, which may allow them to entertain applications filed in Czechia. If you can convince one of them to give you a work visa for a summer internship, that would work. No idea how easy that would be -- if you don't even have an employer in mind, let alone an agreement with one, it sounds like an uphill battle.

Finally, though, do you even need a visa for short stays? You don't disclose your nationality in the question. If your nationality is visa-free for short stays, you won't need a separate visa for the summer unless you want to work. The 90/180 day rule for visa-free access *does not count* days you have spent in the Czech Republic with your Czech type D visa.

Comment: Where do you get the idea that one must apply from the "country of *permanent* residence"?  My impression is that any sort of temporary residence is okay, too, as long as it's not a short visit.  For example, both the French and Greek missions in the US accept applications from foreign students.